# How to return the sum results of two child actors to the parent and print it out

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple results received by the parent and send that off to its parent.

I've got a decent grasp on the basics of akka, and I know how to pass a message and receive a single reply. I'm lost when I need to merge two replies into a single result (and then pass that result on).

For example:
  I want to concurrently add the sum of 1,2,3,4. So I send a message containing 1 and 2 to a child and 3 and 4 to another child. They add up their respective numbers and send a reply to the parent, who would ideally, add up 2 results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `akka` and `java` are slightly similar, you can do

`firstMethod(arguments) + secondMethod(arguments)` as you are trying to add your results. (given from the return values)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a bookkeeping parameter in your parent actor, so in scala code, it would be something like this:

```
object SumAggregationWorker {
  def props: Props = Props[SumAggregationWorker]
  case class ReceivedValue(value: Double) 
}

class SumAggregationWorker extends Actor {
  var totalSum: Int = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case ReceivedValue(value) => 
      totalSum += value
  }
}
```

Another way is to ask instead of tell the other actors, in which case you have the same number of futures as actors asked for summing stuff up. 
With a for-comprehension you can then calculate the final value, but the above is how ud usually handle those cases.
So in case the above actor sends some bunches of numbers to different actors to calculate sums and then report the sums, you either keep some id on the summing up requests so the actor above knows how many sums he is expecting to receive and the id for which to sum it up and can then on receiving the last sum send the result off).

```
for {
 a <- actor1 ? SumUp(valueList1)
 b <- actor3 ? SumUp(valueList2)
} yield extractFromResponse(a) + extractFromResponse(b)
```

where extractFromResponse is some function that interprets the received message and extracts the calculated value.
On this resulting future you yould use an .onComplete call to send the summed up result to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution in Scala which I believe can be converted to Java without too much trouble.  Given your requirement (i.e. using a pool of child workers to collectively perform a computational task), I would suggest using a [router](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/routing.html).

It's a barebone snippet that consists of a `Master` actor which delegates `Add` work to its `Worker` child actors configured as `round-robin` routees.  A mutable `var` of the computation result is kept within the `Master` actor for incremental update upon receipt of work result from the child routees.

```scala
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem, Actor, ActorLogging}
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool

case class CalcSum(l: List[Double])
case class Add(x: Double, y: Double)
case class Result(value: Double)
case object GetResult

class Worker extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def sum(x: Double, y: Double): Result = Result(x + y)

  def receive = {
    case Add(x, y) =>
      sender ! sum(x, y)
    case _ =>
      log.error("Unknown work request!")
  }
}

class Master(nrOfWorkers: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  private var numbers: List[Double] = List.empty[Double]
  private var result: Double = 0.0
  private var nrOfWorkResults: Int = 0

  val workerRouter = context.actorOf(
    Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter"
  )

  def receive = {
    case CalcSum(l: List[Double]) =>
      numbers = l
      result = 0.0
      nrOfWorkResults = 0
      l.foreach(x => workerRouter ! Add(result, x))
    case Result(value) =>
      result += value
      nrOfWorkResults += 1
    case GetResult =>
      if (nrOfWorkResults < numbers.size - 1)
        log.info("Calculation still in progress ...  Please check again later.")
      else
        log.info(s"Result: $result")
  }
}

object Master {
  def props(nrOfWorkers: Int): Props = Props(new Master(nrOfWorkers))
}
```

Note that it's a very basic example and could be refined, for instance, with hotswapping functionality via [context.become](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#become-unbecome) to minimize the need for mutable `var`s, etc.

Test running with a router of 4 `worker` actors to calculate the sum of a numeric list of values 1 to 1,000,000:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

val master = system.actorOf(Master.props(nrOfWorkers = 4), name = "master")

master ! CalcSum( List.iterate(1.0, 1000000)(_ + 1) )

master ! GetResult
// [INFO] [04/05/2019 14:20:44.747] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9]
//   [akka://system/user/master] Result: 5.000005E11
```

Since sum of 1 to N equals `N * (N + 1) / 2` hence can be easily verified.